# No rotation and scaling for subviews

Tags: iphone, rotation

I have one UIView with slider and segment control as a subview.
I am using gesture control to handle rotation and scalling. Now while rotating uiview, the slider and segment control also get rotated.
I dont want rotation and scaling for subviews.
Please help me to sort this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't have your segmented control and slider as subviews of the scaled view.

If necessary, you could have a containing superview that contains the scaled view, segmented control and slider as subviews.

Answer (score 0):

You could "counter-rotate" your subviews when you handle the gesture for rotating the UIView.

Create a `CGAffineTransformRotate` and apply it to your subview in case you do not want it to rotate:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(subview.transform, radians);
subview.transform = transform;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

After you apply the transformation to the subviews, they will be rotated accordingly until you reset the transformation to its default value.

Comment: I think the OP is manually rotating a view using gestures, not rotating the device.

Comment: @jrturton: thanks! my mind sped up a bit while reading the question... anyway, I edited my answer to take into account the proper scenario you mentioned...